# How to color the table in latex?

Tags: tables, color

I would to import the following table in latex with color, how do I make it possible? Many thanks in advance! The colors don't have to be exactly the same.
[image]

Comment: It's weird in your sample that the Step 4 cell in the first column is shorter than the Step 5 cell, but it's the reverse in the third column. I assume that's not intended.

Comment: Please keep `MWE` of your code always...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's the colortbl package, but with `\cline`s, I recommend either the NiceTabular environment from the [nicematrix](https://ctan.org/pkg/nicematrix) package, or using the similar facilities of the tabularray package.

With nicematrix:

```
\documentclass{article}

% for color models
\usepackage{xcolor}

% for nice coloring in tables
\usepackage{nicematrix}

% for multi-row cells
\usepackage{multirow}

%for Helvetica-like sans font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgheros}

\begin{document}

\sffamily

% adds some vertical padding in cells
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

% slightly thicker lines
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.8pt}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{6cm}|}[colortbl-like]
\hline
\rowcolor{yellow} Step 1 & 1 & xx \\
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{d4f0dc} Step 2 & 2 & xx \\
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{b7e0ff} Step 3 & \multirow{4}*{3} & xx\\
\cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
\rowcolor[HTML]{b7e0ff} Step 4 & & xx \\
\cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
\rowcolor[HTML]{b7e0ff}Step 5 & & xx\\
\cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
\rowcolor[HTML]{b7e0ff}Step 6 & & xx\\
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{92d050} Step 7 & 1 & xx\\
\hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: nicetabular output]

With the [tabularray](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package (exactly similar output):

```
\documentclass{article}

% for color models
\usepackage{xcolor}

% for nice coloring in tables
\usepackage{tabularray}

% for multi-row cells
\usepackage{multirow}

%for Helvetica-like sans font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgheros}

\begin{document}

\sffamily

% adds some vertical padding in cells
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

% slightly thicker lines
\setlength{\rulewidth}{0.8pt}

% define colors
\definecolor{mycyan}{HTML}{d4f0dc}
\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{b7e0ff}
\definecolor{mygreen}{HTML}{92d050}
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{6cm}|},
}
\hline
\SetRow{yellow}
Step 1 & 1 & xx \\
\hline
\SetRow{mycyan}
Step 2 & 2 & xx \\
\hline
\SetRow{myblue}
Step 3 & \SetCell[r=4]{wd=1.5cm}{3} & xx\\
\cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
\SetRow{myblue}
Step 4 & & xx \\
\cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
\SetRow{myblue}
Step 5 & & xx\\
\cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
\SetRow{myblue}
Step 6 & & xx\\
\hline
\SetRow{mygreen}
Step 7 & 1 & xx\\
\hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! May I ask, in this case, how do I put all the texts in the middle?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean horizontally center the contents? In the first solution, if you wanted to keep the widths, in the colspec, you could change `p{1.5cm}` to `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}` (for each of the three columns). (Or just use 'c' if you don't want to keep the manual widths.) In the second solution change `p{1.5cm}` to `Q[wd=1.5cm,c]`, etc., for each of the three columns.

Comment: Thanks a lot, how to put the whole table in the middle of the paper?

Comment: Put the part of the paper you want before it, before it (after `\begin{document}`) and the part of the paper you want after it, after it (before `\end{document}`)? You could put `\begingroup` before `\sffamily` and put `\endgroup` after `\end{NiceTabular}` or `\end{tblr}` if you don't want the rest in sans serif. You could also consider putting it in a floating `table` environment. But it is unclear to me exactly what you mean or want to do.

Answer (score 4):

frabjous has provided a solution with `nicematrix`. For information, here is a way a bit shorter to create that tabular with `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}

% for color models
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mycyan}{HTML}{b7e0ff}

% for nice coloring in tables
\usepackage{nicematrix}

%for Helvetica-like sans font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgheros}

\begin{document}

\sffamily

% adds some vertical padding in cells
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

% slightly thicker lines
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.8pt}

\begin{NiceTabular}{p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{6cm}}[colortbl-like,hvlines]
\rowcolor{yellow} Step 1 & 1 & xx \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{d4f0dc} Step 2 & 2 & xx \\
\RowStyle[nb-rows=4,rowcolor=mycyan]{} 
                        Step 3 & \Block[l]{4-1}{3} & xx\\
                        Step 4 &   & xx \\
                        Step 5 &   & xx \\
                        Step 6 &   & xx \\                       
\rowcolor[HTML]{92d050} Step 7 & 1 & xx\\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]